# MongoDB getMore taking up to 1s on UNKNOWN query shown on MongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i was checking query performance with MongoDB compass and i noticed that there is a query taking up to 1s.

I tried to find out the query and don't know about what it is.

Time : 948.44 ms

Info

```
{
    "type": "op",
    "host": "Ubuntu-2004-focal-64-minimal",
    "desc": "conn479199",
    "connectionId": 479199,
    "client": "xxx",
    "clientMetadata": {
        "driver": {
            "name": "nodejs|Mongoose",
            "version": "4.9.1"
        },
        "os": {
            "type": "Windows_NT",
            "name": "win32",
            "architecture": "x64",
            "version": "10.0.22000"
        },
        "platform": "Node.js v18.9.1, LE (unified)",
        "version": "4.9.1|6.6.1"
    },
    "active": "true",
    "currentOpTime": "2022-10-19T12:26:14.835+02:00",
    "effectiveUsers": [
        {
            "user": "xxx",
            "db": "xxx"
        }
    ],
    "threaded": true,
    "opid": 367483579,
    "lsid": {
        "id": "mpMmCEyrQMiAAVagou2NCQ==",
        "uid": "97nSh3DQLZ6SIrtU91vZtdqotiM2qojisDAzHK9Mb6s="
    },
    "secs_running": 0,
    "microsecs_running": 948442,
    "op": "getmore",
    "ns": "snipe.xxx",
    "command": {
        "getMore": {
            "low": 1131828049,
            "high": 1183930404,
            "unsigned": false
        },
        "collection": "xxx",
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "lsid": {
            "id": "mpMmCEyrQMiAAVagou2NCQ=="
        },
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": {
                "$timestamp": "7156167877442142275"
            },
            "signature": {
                "hash": "q/oCXN42KcLFMR9Wy/WNzNaNfMg=",
                "keyId": {
                    "low": 6,
                    "high": 1663608001,
                    "unsigned": false
                }
            }
        },
        "$db": "xxx"
    },
    "planSummary": "COLLSCAN",
    "cursor": {
        "cursorId": {
            "low": 1131828049,
            "high": 1183930404,
            "unsigned": false
        },
        "createdDate": "2022-10-19T10:07:08.178Z",
        "lastAccessDate": "2022-10-19T10:26:13.824Z",
        "nDocsReturned": 1385,
        "nBatchesReturned": 1820,
        "noCursorTimeout": false,
        "tailable": true,
        "awaitData": true,
        "originatingCommand": {
            "aggregate": "xxx",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$changeStream": {}
                }
            ],
            "cursor": {},
            "lsid": {
                "id": "mpMmCEyrQMiAAVagou2NCQ=="
            },
            "$clusterTime": {
                "clusterTime": {
                    "$timestamp": "7156162955409621007"
                },
                "signature": {
                    "hash": "rnVbZaTEDLib0ozeNTSczKqchGk=",
                    "keyId": {
                        "low": 6,
                        "high": 1663608001,
                        "unsigned": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "$db": "xxx"
        },
        "operationUsingCursorId": 367483579
    },
    "numYields": 6,
    "locks": {},
    "waitingForLock": "false",
    "lockStats": {
        "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6
            }
        },
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6
            }
        },
        "Mutex": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "waitingForFlowControl": false,
    "flowControlStats": {}
}
```

The main query should be where there is command etc (i guess).

Anyone can explain me what is this query about ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the output that tells us the answer to your question is the following:

```
        "originatingCommand": {
            "aggregate": "xxx",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$changeStream": {}
                }
            ]
```

Therefore this `getMore` is associated with a Change Stream operation. The Change Stream functionality [helps applications monitor changes on the database](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/). This is coming from the application directly according to the following (as opposed to some internal operation for the database):

```
    "connectionId": 479199,
    "client": "xxx",
    "clientMetadata": {
        "driver": {
            "name": "nodejs|Mongoose",
            "version": "4.9.1"
        },
```

The fact that it is taking 1 second is not always a problem. Change streams usually wait for new data to become available before returning to the client.

Comment: Thanks, i got it now. I use watch on a Collection so thats it.